# template template function definition

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, template-templates

I have a template class called Array

```
template<typename T, int dimension>
class Array<typename T, int dimension>{

    //definition of the class

}
```

I want to write a non-member function cast such that I can cast Array into different type. For example

```
Array<int, 2> a;
Array<float, 2> b = cast<float>(a);
```

How should I write this function? I am more interested in how to declare it instead of how to implement the detailed casting. I have tried

```
template<template<typename T, int dimension> class Array, typename New_T, int dimension>
Array<typename New_T, int dimension> cast(Array<typename T, int dimension> a){

// detailed implementation of casting, which I do not care for this question.

}
```

but it cannot pass the compilation.

Comment: Without having tested it for myself, I'm not sure you actually need a template template here. I think the function can just be:

`template<typename T, int dimension, typename New_T>
Array<New_T, dimension> cast(Array<T, dimension>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I write this function? I am more interested in how to define it instead of how to implement the detailed casting.

I suppose something like

```
template <typename ToT, typename FromT, int Dim>
Array<ToT, Dim> cast (Array<FromT, Dim> const & inA)
 {
   // ...
 }
```

It's useful place `ToT` (to-type) in first position so you can explicit it and let `FromT` and `Dim` deduced from the `inA` value.

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP asks

> Any insight why I have to put it [`ToT`] in the first position?

You don't necessarily have to put `ToT` in first position. But this simplify your life.

The point is that `FromT` and `Dim` are deducible from the `inA` argument; `ToT` isn't deducible from arguments so you have to explicit it.

But if you want to explicit a template parameter, you necessarily have to explicit the preceding parameters. So if you put `ToT` in last position, you have to call `cast()` explicating all template parameters

```
cast<int, 2, float>(a);
```

If you place `ToT` in first position, you have to explicit only it and leave the compiler deduce `FromT` and `Dim` from the argument

```
cast<float>(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For me, the catch is that I have to put ToT (to-type) in the first position. I did that and it fixed my problem. Any insight why I have to put it in the fist position?

Comment: "fist position" :( ? Peace and love, Nan! (sorry: I'm joking; but I've modified my answer trying to respond to your last question).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need template template parameters at all here.  Simple `typename` and `int` parameters will do:

```
template <typename T, int dimension>
class Array
{
    // ...
};

template <typename NewT, typename T, int dimension>
Array<NewT, dimension> cast(const Array<T, dimension>& a)
{
    // ...
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b2d3cd217bf867d)

You only need template template parameters when you want to accept different types of templates.  For instance, if you wanted `cast` to be able to accept an `Array` or a `std::array`, you could use a template template parameter:

```
template<typename NewT, typename T, auto dimension, template<typename, auto> typename ArrayT>
ArrayT<NewT, dimension> cast(const ArrayT<T, dimension>& a)
{
    // ...
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c95ffc1e606ce622)

Note in this case I also changed the type of `dimension` to `auto` since `std::array` uses a `size_t` for its dimension while your `Array` uses `int`.

Comment: Nice explanation! I tried to use the template approach at first and it failed. I found out that the reason, as mentioned by @max66, was because I did not put the NewT type at the first position in the template.